# Determine largest/smallest number

Tags: java, algorithm, logic

im trying to code a java program that gets 5 numbers from user and determines which is the largest and which is the smallest, i got a problem with the logic , i cant quiet figure how to compare all 5 input numbers with one another and determine the largest and smallest :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    public class determine {

    public static void main (String [] args) {

        Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);


            System.out.println("enter 5 numbers : ");
            for(int i=1; i<=5; i++){
            int num=scan.nextInt();

            if (num is bigger than the rest)

                System.out.println(num+" is the largest");

                if (num is smaller than rest )

                    System.out.println(num+" is the smallest");



        }


    }
    }
```

i sorted out the problem , is there any other way around for comparing the numbers rather than setting a value for min and max ?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    public class determine {

    public static void main (String [] args) {

            int max=-9999;
            int min=9999;

        Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);


            System.out.println("enter 5 numbers : ");
            for(int i=1; i<=5; i++){
            int num=scan.nextInt();


                    if (num>max){max=num;}
                    if(num<min){min=num;}       
            }   

                        System.out.println(max+"largest");  
                        System.out.println(min+"smallest");


        }


    }
```

Comment: Put numbers in an array, sort the array and pick first/last element depending on your sort order.

Comment: you can just keep track of the **position** of the value, rather than the value itself.  Assuming they're in an array.  However, you need a variable of some sort, either max or indexOfMax, as you iterate through the numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Just use an extra variable `max` in which you store the largest number you have seen so far. And for each new number you just check if the new number is larger than `max`, then you assign it to `max`. At the end you will have your maximum in `max` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Just initialize min and max values. Then at each iteration, you'll have to make some tests on the number entered by the user and update accordingly min and max. I left the things to complete with ???.

```
                int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
                int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
                System.out.println("enter 5 numbers : ");
                for(int i=1; i<=5; i++){
                    int num=scan.nextInt();

                    if (?????)
                         max = ????;
                    else if (?????)
                         min = ????;
                }
                System.out.println(max+" is the largest");
                System.out.println(min+" is the smallest");
```

Comment: Better to initialize the min and max with the first number then loop over the remaining ones? Or is that just a matter of preference?

Answer (score 0):

Create an array

```
int[] numbers = new int[5];
for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
numbers[i]=scan.nextInt();
}
```

Then sort the array;

```
int max=numbers[0]; 

for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
if (max<num[i]){
max=num[i]
}
}

System.out.println(max+" is the largest");
```

Comment: That doesn't actually "sort" the array although it does find the max (but not the min - easy to see how to add that)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the general idea:

```
package max;

public class Max {
    //assumes integers
    //wrong output for min

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] numbers = {99, 9, 502, 7, 3};
        int indexOfMin = 0;
        int indexOfMax = 0;
        int currentNumber = numbers[0];
        int min = numbers[0];
        int max = numbers[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            currentNumber = numbers[i];
            if (currentNumber >= max) {
                max = currentNumber;
                indexOfMax = i;
            }
            System.out.println("position " + i + " has a value of " + currentNumber);
            System.out.println("current max of " + max + " is at position " + indexOfMax);
        }
        System.out.println("max value of " + max + " is at position " + indexOfMax);
        System.out.println("min value of " + min + " is at position " + indexOfMin); //whoops, wrong output
    }
}
```

I'll leave the user input/output to you.  As food for thought, after you do this, think about how to sort the array.  Don't just look up the answer, try to sort it on your own.  When posting homework, make it clear what you're doing and what you're asking for.

Comment: So now you can start the comparison loop at  `for(int i = 1;` … and you need to add the code to find the `min`.

Comment: well, you *could* start at index 1 instead of 0, but, IMHO, it wouldn't really answer the question as well.  Or not?  I purposefully left out the min code and added a comment to that effect.  To take it to the next stage, maybe not go directly to bubble sort, but break it down into methods.  Of course, we're keeping with all methods being static for the time being, presumably.

Comment: I disagree. When you initialize the min/max values to the first element in the array, you have essentially performed the first pass through the loop - with this first pass being different. As though you had `if(i==0){min = numbers[0]; …} else { if(min > numbers[i]) …`. Leaving the first element outside the loop is marginallymore efficient (no need to test for i==0 each iteration).

Comment: The marginal efficiency comes with a cost to readability in terms of the question which was asked and its context, and to (hopefully) breaking it down to different methods and ultimately sorting the array.   Yes, you're correct, it's inefficient :)     I think there's also a good place to use the ternary if operator, etc, etc...but I was going for clarity.